# Unable to invoke delegate

Tags: c#-4.0

When i form a code expression

```
Expression<Func<string, string>> sub = s => s.Substring(1, 3);
string substr = sub("Hello World");
```

Compiler is not accepting  my delegate call `sub("Hello World");`

What is the issue with the above code segment?

Answer (score 1):

Because `"Sub"` is no longer a delegate.`"Sub"` is an expression tree.

C# compiler will not convert it into executable method.C# compiler will only form a tree indicating what the lambda is doing.

You can either have

```
Func<string, string> sub = s => s.Substring(1, 3);
String getSubstring = sub("Hello World");
```

(or) compile your expression tree

```
  Expression<Func<string, string>> sub = s => s.Substring(1, 3);
  Func<string, string> fn = sub.Compile();
  string str = fn("Hello World");
```

:) Now the C# compiler will be happy to execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile expression first to get the executable delegate:

```
var func = sub.Compile();
string substr = func("Hello World");
```